# How to break a file with specific tag line in python

Tags: python

cHow can break a file in a separate files using a specific tag line example is given bellow.

i have one file called "seq.txt" which contains 500 sequence (string data)

now i want to separate all the sequence file. I have write down a code and sucked into the middle:

```
import glob
import sys

fname = glob.glob("*.txt")

seq= []

for fn in fname:
    f = open(fn)
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if ">" in line:
            print i,line,
```

In put data is like given bellow.

```
> jai_Seq1flkgh456456
HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK
> jai_Seq14564564
HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK
> jai_Seq14654564
HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK
> jai_Seq1werwr456446
HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK
> jai_Seq146456456
HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK
> jai_Seq64654
HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK
```

tag line always start with ">" and i want to use ">" as tag to split the file. after spiting the file   i want to store this file as list given bellow "seq_list". After that i know how to write separate files

```
 seq_list = [ "> jai_Seq1flkgh456456
                HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
                KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
                KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
                KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK",
               "> jai_Seq14564564
                HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
                KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
                KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
                KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK",
               "> jai_Seq14654564
                HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
                KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
                KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
                KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK",
               "> jai_Seq1werwr456446
               HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
               KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
               KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
               KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK",
               "> jai_Seq146456456
               HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
               KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
               KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
               KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK",
                "> jai_Seq64654
               HFSKDFHSKDHFAKHKASDHFKASDHFSKHFSKDFH
               KJSLKDJFLSKDJFSLDKFJSLKDFJSLKDFJLSKD
               KJSLDKJFSKLDFJSDKFJSLDKFJSLKDFJSLDKF
               KSJDFLSJDFKLSDJFSLDKFJSLDKFJSLDKFJLK"]
```

and the end i can loop over "seq_list" and can write down the file

Comment: Do you want to have the `>` lines be in the output, too? How shall the files be named?

Comment: yesss ">" this should be there in file file name should be anything like file_1.txt,file_2.txt, file_3.txt  and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
tf = None # the current target file

with open("seq.txt") as seq:
    for line in seq:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            # close the current target file
            if tf:
                tf.close()
            # open a new target file
            tf = open(line.split()[1], "w")
        else:
            tf.write(line)
```

Running this creates these files:

```
jai_Seq14564564
jai_Seq146456456
jai_Seq14654564
jai_Seq1793857
jai_Seq1flkgh456456
jai_Seq1werwr456446
jai_Seq64654
jai_Seq8347628
```

containing four lines each.

Comment: thanks for your code very short and effective. what if i want to save all these chunk into a list as a list member  rather writing into separate files?

Comment: I don't understand. Please edit your question and describe in detail what out you want. How many files? With what file names? With want content exactly?